# How can I add modules in VSCode

Tags: python, module

[I can't use modules in VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5RXs.png)
I'm using VSCode and I can work normal Python codes in terminal. I installed Numpy modulewith pip command but when I run the code, it isn't work, also I don't get any errors. As you see in image. I deleted and reinstalled VSCode but it didn't solve the problem. I really need your help.

Comment: What happens if you click the "Run" button in VS Code?

Comment: Nothing happens, it just write my file again